# Dissolve by group and get the lowest or highest in other field

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, select, dissolve, qgis-modeler

I've got the next table of attributes:

[image]

I want to perform a dissolve by the first column (date) and get:
- Earliest value by group in the second column.
- Latest value by group in the third column.

There is any easy way to do so ? The aim is to do so into the modeler so I would try to avoid complex code, or at least an easy way to implement it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

Field *"earliest"*

```
minimum("start_t", group_by:="my_date")
```

Field *"latest"*

```
maximum("end_t", group_by:="my_date")
```

Comment: I'm glad, thanks. And sorry for this shoddy post, my computer was unstable... Just as a side note, this aggregates function (`group_by`) may not work for QGIS versions older than 2.16.

Comment: I didn't try it yet but even if it doesn't work into 2.18 you gave me some ideas to do it ;-)